# how to export tags and computed functions to main App.vue from components in VueCLI

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-cli

I'm at the very start with VUE CLI 3, and was wondering if I could make clean my code importing from the components to the main App.vue such things like tags inside the template of those components, or even computed functions of that components, here on detail my problem:

This is one of my components (header), and I want to export that input tag and its computed function to the main App.vue without precisely write all that template code and scripts in there.

```
<template>
    <div>
       <input type='text' v-model='search' placeholder='Search for Tittle or Author'/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:"header",
    props:{
        header:Object
    },
    computed: {
       filteredTitles:function()
       {
         return this.bookLists.filter((data)=>{return data.title.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())})
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is my App.Vue file already with that component imported, but the point is even the element already was imported , the input doesn't show up, unless I write its code inside the App.vue template tag in fact.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="card-flipping">
      <books v-for="(books,index) in bookLists" v-bind:key="index" v-bind:books="books" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import books from "./components/books.vue";
import header from './components/header.vue';

export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    header,
    books,

  },
  data() {
    return {
      bookLists: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getJsonData() {
      fetch(" https://api.myjson.com/bins/zyv02 ", {
        method: "GET"
      })
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(bookStore => {
          this.bookLists = bookStore.books;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  computed: {
       filteredTitles:function()
       {
         return this.bookLists.filter((data)=>{return data.title.toUpperCase().includes(this.search.toUpperCase())})
       }
    },
  created() {
    this.getJsonData();
  }
};
</script>
```

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question for formatting. You should format it correctly yourself next time. Also check your spelling, "fucntion" makes you look sloppy and careless and such questions don't tend to attract good answers. You may want to read [ask] and then [edit] your question to add the code you've tried. Include what happened when you ran it, and what you expected to happen instead. Any errors?

Comment: Ok thanks !!Next time would be more careful